# Create a CSV file from JSON String Java

Tags: java, json, csv

I am creating a stand-alone java program. I have the code to create CSV file and it works when I put it as a string variable **(eg: below)**

```
this.btnCreateFile = new JButton("Create File");
    this.btnCreateFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            lblOutput.setText(textArea.getText());

            String jsonString = "{\"infile\": [{\"field1\": 11,\"field2\": 12,\"field3\": 13},{\"field1\": 21,\"field2\": 22,\"field3\": 23},{\"field1\": 31,\"field2\": 32,\"field3\": 33}]}";

            JSONObject output;
            try {
                output = new JSONObject(jsonString);


                JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("infile");

                File file=new File("/tmp2/fromJSON.csv");
                String csv = CDL.toString(docs);
                FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

But, when I change the JSON string to get from a textArea, it shows *'A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]'* **(eg: below)**

```
this.btnCreateFile = new JButton("Create File");
    this.btnCreateFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            lblOutput.setText(textArea.getText());


            JSONObject output;
            try {
                output = new JSONObject(textArea);


                JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("infile");

                File file=new File("/tmp2/fromJSON.csv");
                String csv = CDL.toString(docs);
                FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? Thanks

This is the JSON String:

```
{"infile": [{"field1": 11,"field2": 12,"field3": 13},
        {"field1": 21,"field2": 22,"field3": 23},
        {"field1": 31,"field2": 32,"field3": 33}]}
```

Comment: does the text in the text are begins and ends with { and } respecively ?

Comment: Looks like a typo, try `output = new JSONObject(textArea.getText());` .

Comment: @Berger , Thanks for the reply, I have also tried that way also and the error is still the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062056/a-jsonobject-text-must-begin-with-at-1-character-2-line-1-with-error

Comment: That didnt work, Sorry

Comment: In your post I can't see the type of `textArea` variable

Comment: It's a JTextArea type. Because I made it as global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
output = new JSONObject(textArea);
```

into

```
output = new JSONObject(textArea.getText());
```

I also suggest to print the output of:

```
textArea.getText()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, but I have tried that solution as well, yet the same error comes.

Comment: Have you tried to print the content of `textArea.getText()`?

Comment: I think there's the problem because I don't get the string which I typed in the textArea. Any idea why is that?

Comment: The console shows something starting like this: jjavax.swing.JTextArea[,0,0,522x170,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicBorders$MarginBorder@4bf44f0a,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],

Comment: Very likely `textArea.getText()` is not returning what you thought. Have a look at JTextArea methods to see how get the text content.

Comment: But I can set a JLabel to textArea, so that I can see the  exact text I type in that label. lblOutput.setText(textArea.toString());

Comment: If you are right, printing `textArea.toString()` should return the json.

Comment: Thanks a lot @freedev for finding the error. I will look on to how I can print the textArea texts to the console.

Answer (score -1):

The text `{` may not getting detected. Keep the escape character for flower braces.